# How to fix PHP notice: "Trying to get property of non-object in" (parsing XML)

Tags: php, xml

I am parsing data from XML in PHP. I want to display it, but I got Notice: "Trying to get property of non-object in". It also doesnt display the data

My PHP file:

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
$result = $xml->tittle->topic[$i]->name;    
}

echo $result;

?>
```

My XML file:

```
<tittle>

<topic>
<name>PHP</name>
</topic>

<topic>
<name>JS</name>
</topic>

<topic>
<name>CSS</name>
</topic>

</tittle>
```

Browser output:

```
Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6

Notice: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 6
```

Comment: The root element of the XML is not a property, you should skip it and do `$result = $xml->topic[$i]->name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the error using below code just remove "title"

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml');

for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
{
$result = $xml->topic->name;    
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `tittle` is the root element, which will be found directly in `$xml`, so you can just use `$xml->topic` instead of `$xml->tittle->topic`.
2. You should loop over all elements in the array, regardless of how many there are, and not hardcode that in your PHP file.

The result would look something like this:

```
<?php

$xml = simplexml_load_file('xml.xml');

foreach ($xml->topic as $topic)
{
    echo (string) $topic->name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in comments, the object returned by `simplexml_load_file` does not include a property for the root element. You need to omit that from the chain.

A few more comments:

- Your loop overwrites `$result` in each iteration, so you'll get just the last node. Possibly, you'll want `$result` to be an array
- You need to convert the SimpleXml node to a string (in case you want a string).
- You expect three nodes, but it would be better to make that more dynamic so that a change to the number of topics in the XML will not break the code

So here is how I would suggest to code the loop:

```
foreach($xml->topic as $topic) {
   $result[] = (string) $topic->name;    
}
```

Now `$result` will have `["PHP", "JS", "CSS"]`